# Databricks dbutils.fs.ls() error Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtilsParallel is not whitelisted

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

When executing dbtuils.fs.ls() to list files in Databricks I get the error:

```
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtilsParallel(org.apache.spark.SparkContext) is not whitelisted.
```

I also get the error when I try dbtuils.fs.ls().

Unfortunately, the following failed `spark.databricks.pyspark.enablePy4JSecurity False`

I have done some research and can someone advise if any of the following will fix the issue:

- Enabling credential passthrough for standard and high-concurrency clusters.
- Configuring credential passthrough and initializing storage resources in ADLS accounts.
- Accessing ADLS resources directly when credential passthrough is enabled.
- Accessing ADLS resources through a mount point when credential passthrough is enable

Thanks

Comment: what cluster type are you using right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#py4jsecuritypy4jsecurityexception--is-not-whitelisted)

> The error you are facing is because, when utilizing a High Concurrency cluster and enabling credential pass through, this problem occurs with various library operations.
> When you visit a method that Azure Databricks hasn't expressly designated as safe for Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough clusters, this issue is raised.

**To workaround you can:**

- Use a different cluster mode as a workaround if it describes your situation.
- Update `spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation`  to  `false` for this your cluster needs to be with **no isolation shared** access mode
- Use **standard** clusters in your case as a workaround.

[image]